# How can I cascade create and remove entities with bidirectional self-reference in Hibernate and Spring Boot?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to cascade create and delete entity with bidirectional self reference, but it's not working.

- When cascade type is ALL - entity is creating but not removing;
- When cascade type is REMOVE - entity is removing but not creating;
- Can't use fetch = Lazy because I need to validate all fields before removing, and anyway I need to get all child fields;

Using Spring 3 and Postgresql

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "field")
public class Field {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.BIGINT)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_field_id")
    private Field parentField;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentField", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade =  CascadeType., orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Field> childFields = new HashSet<>();

}
```

**Test code:**

```
final Field firstLevel = createField("firstLevel");
final Field secondLevel = createField("secondLevel");
secondLevel.setParentField(firstLevel);
firstLevel.getChildFields().add(secondLevel);

final Field thirdLevel = createField("thirdLevel");
thirdLevel.setParentField(secondLevel);
secondLevel.getChildFields().add(thirdLevel);
fieldRepo.save(firstLevel);

// Checking child fields saved
final Field filedWithChild = fieldRepo.findById(1L).get();
filedWithChild.getChildFields().forEach(field -> Assert.isTrue(field.getId() != null));

// Trying to remove second level
log.info("Prepare to delete");
fieldRepo.deleteById(2L);
final Optional<Field> byId = fieldRepo.findById(2L);
Assert.isTrue(byId.isEmpty(),"Second level was not removed");
```

**The logs show that after the deletion there is no sql delete request itself**

```
2023-05-19T10:56:55.109+05:00  INFO 31018 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.springbatchtest.app.SpringBatch      : Prepare to delete
2023-05-19T10:56:55.110+05:00 DEBUG 31018 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select f1_0.id,c1_0.parent_field_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.name,f1_0.name,p1_0.id,p1_0.name,p1_0.parent_field_id from field f1_0 left join field c1_0 on f1_0.id=c1_0.parent_field_id left join field p1_0 on p1_0.id=f1_0.parent_field_id where f1_0.id=?
Hibernate: select f1_0.id,c1_0.parent_field_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.name,f1_0.name,p1_0.id,p1_0.name,p1_0.parent_field_id from field f1_0 left join field c1_0 on f1_0.id=c1_0.parent_field_id left join field p1_0 on p1_0.id=f1_0.parent_field_id where f1_0.id=?
2023-05-19T10:56:55.112+05:00 DEBUG 31018 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.parent_field_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.name from field c1_0 where c1_0.parent_field_id=?
Hibernate: select c1_0.parent_field_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.name from field c1_0 where c1_0.parent_field_id=?
2023-05-19T10:56:55.114+05:00 DEBUG 31018 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.parent_field_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.name from field c1_0 where c1_0.parent_field_id=?
Hibernate: select c1_0.parent_field_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.name from field c1_0 where c1_0.parent_field_id=?
2023-05-19T10:56:55.120+05:00 DEBUG 31018 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select f1_0.id,c1_0.parent_field_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.name,f1_0.name,p1_0.id,p1_0.name,p1_0.parent_field_id from field f1_0 left join field c1_0 on f1_0.id=c1_0.parent_field_id left join field p1_0 on p1_0.id=f1_0.parent_field_id where f1_0.id=?
Hibernate: select f1_0.id,c1_0.parent_field_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.name,f1_0.name,p1_0.id,p1_0.name,p1_0.parent_field_id from field f1_0 left join field c1_0 on f1_0.id=c1_0.parent_field_id left join field p1_0 on p1_0.id=f1_0.parent_field_id where f1_0.id=?
2023-05-19T10:56:55.122+05:00 DEBUG 31018 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.parent_field_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.name from field c1_0 where c1_0.parent_field_id=?
Hibernate: select c1_0.parent_field_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.name from field c1_0 where c1_0.parent_field_id=?
2023-05-19T10:56:55.124+05:00 DEBUG 31018 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.parent_field_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.name from field c1_0 where c1_0.parent_field_id=?
Hibernate: select c1_0.parent_field_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.name from field c1_0 where c1_0.parent_field_id=?
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using spring-boot and it's fairly simple to create database functionality with spring data https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ I'd suggest to create either a special 'getByParentId' and/or 'deleteByParentId' and call the methods seperate from code.